# Adding chat lines to richtextbox

Tags: c#

I am using library called SmartIrc4Net, and i want to display all messages into richtextbox, but problem is that i read message normally and then i cant put text into RichTextBox.

By original my method is static but i removed static and it still kinda works:

```
private void HandleChannelMessage(object sender, IrcEventArgs e)
{
    string msg = e.Data.Nick + " " + e.Data.Message;
    addLineToChat(msg);
    MessageBox.Show(msg); //If i add this its adding messages else not
 }
```

My addLineToChat is simple method to appendText

```
  private void addLineToChat(string msg)
  {
     richTextBox.AppendText(msg + Environment.NewLine);
  }
```

So problem is that if i put in method MessageBox.Show(msg); it displays every messaage and when i click ok its added to richtextbox, but i remove this line its not adding any text.

Comment: have you tried stepping through the mode to see what is happening?

Comment: Your code looks perfectly fine. Are you sure the HandleChannelMessage is invoked correctly? Set a breakpoint inside the method to see if it's invoked in the first place.

Comment: Its invoking as MessageBox always displays message...